# Regex branch name pattern conditional

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the branch name using regex and then use it in a case.
Does anyone know how it could work?

Possible names are:

- release/v1.1  -> release
- master -> master
- develop -> develop

```
BRANCH="release/v1.1";
#BRANCH="master";
#BRANCH="develop";


#branch_name=`expr "${BRANCH}" : '^\(release\)\/v[0-9]\.[0-9]$'`
branch_name=`expr "${BRANCH}" : '^\(master)|(release\)\/v[0-9]\.[0-9]$'`
echo $branch_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `cut`?

```
| cut -f1 -d"/"
```

This uses a slash as a separator and only shows the first entry:

```
Prompt> echo "master" | cut -f1 -d"/"
master

Prompt> echo "develop" | cut -f1 -d"/"
develop

Prompt> echo "release/v1.1 you can put whatever here :-)" | cut -f1 -d"/"
release
```

**Edit:** In order to use this to assign to variable `branch_name`, this is what you need to do:

```
branch_name=$(echo $BRANCH | cut -f1 -d"/")
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited my answer so you know how to use the pipe result as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed and put every alternative in it's own group

The part `((release)/v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` matches release followed by `/` and 1+ digits, optionally followed by `.` and 1+ digits.

In the replacement use group 2 and group 4.

```
for BRANCH in release/v1.1 master develop; do
  sed -E 's~^((release)/v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|(develop|master))$~\2\4~' <<< "$BRANCH"
done
```

Output

```
release
master
develop
```

See the [regex groups](https://regex101.com/r/lOzc9y/1).

You could also use a bit shorter version of the pattern with awk, setting the field separator to `/` and when there is a match print field 1.

```
awk -F'/' '/^(release\/v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|develop|master)$/ {print $1}' <<< "$BRANCH"
```